# How to invoke lambda function using AWS Mobile Hub Helper?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-mobilehub, amazon-mobile-hub

I can't currently invoke a lambda in Swift using AWS Mobile Helper.

I've succeed to configure my project to identify user using Cognito User Pools and Cognito Federated Identities.

But now invoking lambda function lead to a crash:
`terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Before crash there are the following log:

```
AWSiOSSDK v2.4.11 [Debug] AWSInfo.m line:122 | -[AWSServiceInfo     initWithInfoDictionary:checkRegion:] | Couldn't read the region configuration from Info.plist for the client. Please check your `Info.plist` if you are providing the SDK configuration values through `Info.plist`.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The service configuration is `nil`. You need to configure `Info.plist` or set `defaultServiceConfiguration` before using this method.'
```

And here is the code:

```
let lambda = AWSLambda.defaultLambda()

lambda.invoke(myRequest, completionHandler: {
            (myAnswer: AWSLambdaInvocationResponse?, error: NSError?) in

   print("ERROR HERE: \(error)")
   let payload = myAnswer?.payload
   print("PAYLOAD HERE: \(payload)")

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Mobile Hub or Mobile Hub Helper you should use the classes that it provides.  When you instantiate the CloudLogic singleton it sets the service configuration up.

So rather than AWSLambda.defaultLambda you should use AWSCloudLogic.defaultCloudLogic it's methods will manage the permissions issues as soon as it is instantiated.

You can get an example by using the mobile hub to download a sample app that uses cloud logic.

I put together a brief diagram of the mobile hub

[mobile hub diagram](https://github.com/BruceBuckland/SignIn-awsmhh/blob/add-username-syncinc/mobile%20hub%20diagram.pdf)

Comment: Thank you Bruce. I've already read your great PDF. Does this mean I have to implement others stuff only to invoke lambda functions?

Comment: I followed your sample, add stuff to Info.plist. Things go one step further but there still a crash and this log: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The service configuration is `nil`. You need to configure `Info.plist` or set `defaultServiceConfiguration` before using this method.'`

Comment: I compared your example and the one given by AWS to try to understand what the missing point. They are really different!

Comment: Dom, your code was using AWSLambda, you don't need to use other mobile hub helper stuff... but you do need to use AWSCloudLogic instead of  AWSLambda.  AWSCloudLogic is the mobile hub wrapper to Lambda.  The init for the class DOES DO the service configuration registration.  if you want to use AWSLambda and not AWSCLoudLogic, then look at the init in AWSCloudLogic and do the same service configuration setup

Comment: Yes, I understand this. And I want to follow your advices by using AWSCloudLogic. Unfortunately there is a problem on configuration. Log message ask to configure `Info.plist` but I don't know what kind of data are needed.

Comment: Dom, good.  So the problem is now an Info.plist configuration.  What is the exact error message?  ... we need to know which constructor is logging the error.  If it is CloudLogic, it is looking for the CloudLogic tag (all it wants is the region), but it can also be logged by AWSLambda if you are using that directly (using defaultLambda).  Remember the weird AWS key structure... the CloudLogic key should be Info.plist->AWS->CloudLogic->Default->Region ... if you forget to layer that Default in there .. the key is missing

Comment: Dom... Also...if you just do a straight config on Mobile Hub, make the app do authentication and lambda... download the app... you will have an example Info.plist... all set up.  And it will have all the proper IAM roles and policies which will be helpful if you get past this problem of having a nil serviceConfiguration.

Comment: Bruce, my Info.plist already contain CloudLogic tag and region. I've used a straight config from mobile hub and generate Sample application to obtain something I can study.

Comment: And glad to hear you fixed it!  Please accept the answer and let us know what you think the issue was.